# Assigning values to an object in JS

Tags: javascript

I've an object as below:

```
default = {
    name: "",
    details: {
        age: "",
        place: ""
        country: ""
    },
    contact: {
        email: null,
        phone: null
    }
}
```

Now, I've another object as:

```
data = {
    name: "Abc",
    details: {
        age: "27,
    },
    contact: {
        email: "abc@xyz.com"
    }
}
```

Want to achieve:

```
result = {
    name: "Abc",
    details: {
        age: 27,
        place: ""
        country: ""
    },
    contact: {
        email: "abc@xyz.com",
        phone: null
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get the values from `data` and put it in `default`. Currently I'm checking if the key exists, then assign value, else keep default. But it's a long process. Is there a JS helper function or something that I can use for this?

`Object.assign(default, data)` is only copying the property values and not going deep.

Comment: It's not the same one as Mike C suggested. It's a completely different situation.

Comment: I'm looking for deep cloning. The `Object.assign()` only copies the property values.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate. here is a deep-copy method i made: https://jsfiddle.net/8cyLp0os/   Inspect/Look at console.log to see output.  I tried to respond earlier but had to hit 50rep before I could post.